Docker Command Not Found During GitLab CI/CD Pipeline Execution
Why docker is not found? I want to deploy a Next.js app to AWS ECS.
λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
$ echo "Building the Docker image..."
Building the Docker image...
$ docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .
/bin/sh: eval: line 163: docker: not found

Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127

gitlab-ci.yml
image: docker:20.10.7 # Use a specific Docker image

services:
  - docker:20.10.7-dind # Docker-in-Docker service

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

variables:
  DOCKER_IMAGE: 'my-repository'
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: eu-central-1
  AWS_ECR_REGISTRY: 767397666295.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
  AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY: my-repository
  ECS_CLUSTER: my-cluster
  ECS_SERVICE: my-service
  ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: my-task-def

before_script:
  - docker --version
  - docker info
  - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  - aws configure set default.region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker version # Verify Docker is installed and running
    - docker info
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker tag $DOCKER_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA $AWS_ECR_REGISTRY/$AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker push $AWS_ECR_REGISTRY/$AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY:$CI_COMMIT_SHA

test:
  stage: test
  image: node:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run test

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: amazon/aws-cli
  script:
    - aws ecs update-service --cluster $ECS_CLUSTER --service $ECS_SERVICE --task-definition $ECS_TASK_DEFINITION --force-new-deployment

Dockerfile:
# Use an official Node.js runtime as a parent image
FROM node:18-alpine

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Build the Next.js application
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=""
RUN npm run build

# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the Next.js application
CMD ["npm", "start"]


Which of your jobs fails? Deploy?

I think the build here: docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .

I'm unable to find this line in your gitlab-ci.yml

Strange in the log before error I see docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG . but in the gitlab-ci.yml I have docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .. Is it possible that an oldlcached version is executed? How can I clean cache?

There is also a echo "Building the Docker image..." in your log that is not on your yaml file. Are you sure there is nothing else that causes this output?

Strange though that this error happens in the first stage, so it is not depending any previous one.
